# Performance issues - Visible and RightToLeft in Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, visible, right-to-left

I'm doing some performance minded work on an existing winforms project.
This form is made dynamically rather than at design time, and loads a few dozen user controls, as well as binding them to a DataSet object with a small set of data.

Using some profiling tools (ANTS, Avicode), i can see most of time, around 50%, is taken by the code i have to show a tab page i have on the form. drilling down, i see it divides roughly in half to two operations:

1) a long line of VisibleChanged/SetVisibility/SetVisibleCore operations, all in the winforms namespaces. How can i know if the time it takes (4.5 seconds in my case) is sane? I do have a lot of user controls in my form.

2) A long line of RightToLeftChanged operations, again, around 4.5 seconds. Here too, I'm wondering if this is expected/sane performance of WinForms.

any advice regarding finding the performance issues here or whether the performance i'm getting is normal would go a long way to help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using anchors or docking to autosize the controls? Are you using many textboxes or other controls with opacity? Are you using SuspendLayout / ResumeLayout?

Comment: Docking - Definitely, most controls are docked top to create a "stack" sort of view. I don't use opacity. I am using Suspend/Resume Layout when adding new controls.

Comment: i just tried it myself. adding 10 panels (DockStyle.Top) with 4 textboxs in each panel take 250ms without layout suspending and 40ms with layout suspending. Please provide some code.

Comment: try setting form.visible to false, doing all the add controls, setting visible back to true after that. This made my winform with 400 pictureboxes redraw instantly instead of a few seconds long viewable redraw nightmare. SuspendLayout also made a difference, but far less.